# Question regarding the base points of the shapes corresponding to Dyck words

Tags: combinatorics

For a given Catalan number corresponding to the Dyck words of length $2n$ let $p$ be the number of points where the shape is based and let $\hbar$ is total number of shapes having $p$.

For example, for $n=4$ shown in the graph, we have:

For $p_2$ -> $\hbar_2$=5

For $p_3$ -> $\hbar_3$=5

For $p_4$ -> $\hbar_4$=3

For $p_5$ -> $\hbar_5$=1.

My two observations which I seek a help to prove:

1) $\hbar_2$ is always equal to $\hbar_3$, how to prove this?

2) For a given $C_n$; $\hbar_2$ or $\hbar_3$ always equal to $C_{n-1}$

[image]

Comment: $h_2 = C_{n-1}$ because a path is in $p_2$ if and only if it is still a valid path after removing the first and last segments. $h_3 = C_{n-1}$ comes from $h_2 = C_{n-1}$ and the recurrence relation $C_{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n C_iC_{n-i}$.

Comment: thanks for that. I did not get the second part; how the recurrence relation mentioned proves that h2=h3?

Comment: Suppose the extra hit to the base splits the Dyck word into Dyck words of length $2k$ and $2(n-k)$. Since there are no more extra hit to the base, the number of possible paths are $h_{2, k} = C_{k-1}$ and $h_{2, n-k} = C_{n-k-1}$, respectively. Then you sum over $k$ and use the recurrence relation to claim that the sum is $C_{n-1}$.